# Jinja2 Parsing External JS Files

Tags: javascript, django, jinja2

I currently use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src={% static 'app.js' %}></script>
```

to retrieve my JavaScript file.

However, `app.js` tries to use Jinja2 tags with are not translated when I import my script in this fashion.

An example, of a line causing an error in `app.js` would be

```
$('#tag').click(function() {
  window.location.href = "{% url 'Project.views.views.viewname' %}";
});
```

How do I force `{% url 'Project.views.views.viewname' %}` to be translated to a url if it is located in an external JS file?